# How to install varnish in Windows 10

Tags: varnish, windows10

I wants to install varnish in my windows pc. Please provide proper link or detail about varnish installation.

Answer (score 0):

See below step by step guidelines to configure varnish with Magento 2 and Apache

**1) Install Varnish on server**

- Connect your server using putty or terminal and run below command to
  install varnish

> sudo apt-get install varnish

- Once you install varnish you can check installed varnish version by
  running below command

> varnishd -V

**2) Configure Varnish in Magento**

**Step 1:**

- Login to Magento admin panel
- Go to stores > Configuration > General > Web > Base URLs (Secure)
- Change the Offloader header to X-Forwarded-Proto from SSL_OFFLOADED
  and save the configuration

**Step 2:**

- Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache
- Change the Caching Application to Varnish Cache (Recommended) from the Built-in Cache.
- Flush Magento cache

**3) Add varnish.vcl on server**

- Login to ssh with root user and Rename the file
  [MAGENTO_ROOT]/var/varnish.vcl to [MAGENTO_ROOT]/var/default.vcl
- Go to the location of varnish by the following command

> cd /etc/varnish/

- Once you install varnish you can check installed varnish version by
  running below command

> mv default.vcl default.vcl.original mv

> /var/www/html/magento/var/default.vcl.

**4) Check DAEMON_OPTS**

- Open the /etc/default/varnish, locate for the DAEMON_OPTS. It should
  display like below

> ```
> DAEMON_OPTS=”-a :80 \
>
> T localhost:6082 \
> f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
> p thread_pool_min=1 \
> p thread_pool_max=1500 \
> p http_resp_hdr_len=42000 \
> p http_resp_size=98304 \
> S /etc/varnish/secret \
> s malloc,768m”
> ```

**5) Change varnish port from 6081 to 80**

- To change varnish port from 6081 to 80, we need to edit the system
  service configuration as follows:

> Sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/varnish.service

- The above command will open a file in which you need to find the line
  as below:

> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T
> 127.0.0.1:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

- And comment it with the hash symbol as below:

> #ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m

- Below this line, add a line as following:

> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T
> 127.0.0.1:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1536m

**6) Change the Apache listening port from 80 to 8080**

- Open the Apache ports configuration file and change it as follows:

> Nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
>
> Listen 80 -> Listen 8080
>
> Nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento.conf
>
> <VirtualHost *:80> -> <VirtualHost *:8080>

**7) Restart varnish and apache service**

- Now we need to run following commands for restart varnish and apache
  service and also for check their status:

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>
> sudo service apache2 restart
>
> sudo service apache2 status
>
> sudo service varnish restart
>
> sudo service varnish status

- You can check the ports by the following command:

> sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :80

**8) Configure Varnish for the HTTPS or SSL**

- To make the varnish work with the HTTPS or SSL, you need to do
  reverse proxy. For reverse proxy you must enable the following modes:

  sudo a2enmod SSL
  sudo a2enmod proxy
  sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
  sudo a2enmod proxy_http
- To enable reverse proxy to do as follows:

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento-ssl.conf

- Locate the SSLEngine on and paste the following lines before the
  SSLEngine on

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port “443”
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto “https”
- Restart the apache by this command:

> sudo service apache2 restart

- Also, check the status of apache by this command:

> sudo service apache2 status

**9) Verify varnish cache is working or not**

- To verify varnish is working or not, you can check it by the
  following command:

> curl -I -v –location-trusted ‘https://www.example.com’

- Using the below command will provide you with an updating list of URL
  requests going to the back-end (Misses).

> varnishtop -i BereqURL

- The below command will provide you with an updated list of ALL
  requests.

> Varnishtop -i ReqURL

Also you can see the blog [here](https://www.zealousweb.com/how-to-configure-varnish-in-apache-with-magento-2/).

Thanks

Comment: OP is running Windows OS...

Comment: @ZealousWeb Thanks for solution but  as you say in step 4 /etc/default/varnish file is not available in my case.It is varnish installation issue? command `varnish -V` returns version details and command `varnishd -d -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl` take input start,quit and display running.